# Tkinter Treeview with images: Invalid state name pyimage2

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have been trying to insert images and values into a treeview to create a calendar that has images for certain days, but I encountering errors. In the initialization of my calendar object, I create item ids to be inserted into on the creation of the calendar dates

```
    # store items ids, used for insertion later
    imgs= [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('sb.png')), ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('sp.png')), ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('sb3.png')) ]
    self._items = [self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values='', image= imgs) for _ in range(6)]
```

then later I have

```
self._calendar.item(item, values=dates)
```

the .item() comes from the treeview and the (item,...) is replacing the inserted items from above with dates

The error I receive with this method is: 
_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name pyimage2
[This is the closest solution I can find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468229/problems-with-images-in-pythons-tkinter)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not too familiar with TK as python GUI

Comment: Change to `self.imgs=...` to prevent *garbage collected*

Comment: this change returns the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: `_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name pyimage2`

- You don't need `PIL`, if you use `*.png` images

  > ```
  > imgs= [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('sb.png')), 
  >        ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('sp.png')), 
  >        ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('sb3.png')) ]
  > ```

  - ***Change to***

    > **Note**: `self.imgs` is needed to prevent garbage collected!

    ```
    self.imgs = [tk.PhotoImage(file='share/sb.png'),
                 tk.PhotoImage(file='share/sp.png'),
                 tk.PhotoImage(file='share/sb3.png')
                ]
    ```
- You loop of `range(6)`, without using the Range Value!
  Therefore you `insert` the **whole Image List** `image=imgs` into the `treeview`!

  > **Note**: This ist the cause of **_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name pyimage2**
  >
  > ```
  > self._items = 
  >   [self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values='', image= imgs) for _ in range(6)]
  > ```

  - ***Change to***

    ```
    self._calendar = ttk.Treeview(self)
    self._items = 
      [self._calendar.insert('', 'end', image=self.imgs[idx) for idx in range(3)]
    ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: Thank you that got rid of the error, but is there something more I have to do to have it show up in the frames column?

Comment: Now it appears in the tk frame along with all the correct value, but it appears as pyimage2 not as the actual image, i am using grid GM

Comment: Very messy because I have been trying to figure out my issue for a while now https://gist.github.com/Ishcadore/14d4eb04ed5b346c377cdb0b738080a2