# Tkinter and some kind of issue when trying to display images

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, gif, google-chrome-os

First off, I'm very new to Python and coding in general. I'm using Python, Tkinter, and Idle version 3.7.3. I'm using an HP Chromebook, with Chrome OS Version 81.0.4044.141.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Image Example')
img = PhotoImage(file = 'python.gif')
label = Label(window, image = img)

label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

As you can see above, this is the small snippet of code that I'm having issues with. As far as I understand, everything is written correctly and the file "python.gif" is in the correct directory. For reference this is what the image should look like:

[python.gif (normal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeaDk.gif)

But when I run the program, this is what I get:

[python.gif (screenshot of running program)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4omK.jpg)

That's the result 99% of the time, but I should mention that there have been a RARE number of occasions where the image displayed correctly upon program execution. However, I do not know how to replicate that. Also for more context, I've tried other images to see what happened. I found a free .pgm image to try as an example, and upon execution either I got the same result, or half of the image would appear correctly while the bottom half (also sometimes this would be reversed and the top half would be affected) would be "blacked out".

In conclusion, I wanted to ask if anybody has an idea of what's going on. I'm not sure if this is a hardware issue (because I can view all mentioned images in a normal image viewing app with no problems), or if this has something to do with Python/Tkinter.

Any assistance is very appreciated! Please and Thank You!

Comment: Use `PIL.Image` and `PIL.PhotoImage` instead. Read [Problems with Images in Python's Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15468267/7414759)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately I don't believe it's the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I did try it. I downloaded Pillow to have access to the PIL and I rewrote the code with all the new information. I changed the test image I was using to the Lenna image and upon execution the window that appears outputs a completely blacked out image, or half of the image is a black bar. Also, the half that is blacked out changes every time the program is executed.

Could you elaborate on the image conversion, as well?

Comment: ***changes every time the program is executed.***: Sounds more like a damaged `Tkinter` installation. Provide a link to the image in question so i can verify the image.

Comment: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lenna_(test_image).png#/media/File:Lenna_(test_image).png)

Comment: This image are verfied multiple times. If you only can't display it using `Tkinter` then reinstall ...

Comment: As far as my limited knowledge tells me, I've reinstalled Python, Tkinter, and Idle.  

Upon execution it seems the problem still persists.  

As detailed as I can describe it, here is what's happening:  

The window appears with the image inside it. It looks like for some reason the image is divided into four equal parts, like four horizontal "stripes". When I run the program repeatedly, the sections that display the image properly seems to be randomly chosen. Sometimes the whole image is blacked out, other times it's the top/bottom half, and sometimes only a single quarter displays.

Comment: All three are version 3.7.3, if I'm looking at the correct information in my packages list. And in my post I wrote that I'm using an HP Chromebook, so my OS (once again, if I'm looking at the right information) is Chrome OS Version 81.0.4044.141.

Comment: Okay, I did that. Thanks so much for taking the time to try to help me out with this.

Comment: The python-idle tag does not apply unless your program runs differently (worse) when you run it from an IDLE editor than when you run it with python from a Terminal.  I doubt this is the case here.  The google-chrome tag is for the Google Chrome web browser.  You are not running tkinter in the browser.  tcl/tk and Tkinter runs on Linux and Google Chrome OS is based on the Linux kernal, but the tcl/tk port may not be bug free.  Run `python -m test -j0 -ugui` in a terminal and see if at least test_tcl, test_tk, test_ttk_textonly, and test_ttk_gui_only all pass.

Comment: Thanks for responding and explaining the tags, I wasn't sure what to pick.  
I entered the command you suggested, and a lot happened, but I didn't see anything that referenced those specific items. However, would you happen to know what it means if the test comes back as a Failure? The output is telling me that one test is OK, but nine have failed:  
  
test_builtin, test_dict, test_doctest, test_doctest2, test_exceptions, test_grammar, test_opcodes, test_types, test_unittest  
  
If you're familiar with this, could you please clarify what this test is and what these results mean?